# Unloading Child AppDomain kills Parent

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, appdomain

I am trying to figure out AppDomains.

I use following code to run the current application once more in a new child AppDomain with an argument:

```
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewAppDomain", null);
    domain.ExecuteAssemblyByName(currentAssembly.FullName, "argument");
```

It works fine, however, when I try to unload it via `AppDomain.Unload(domain);`, it also kills Parent it was called from.

In the debug output I can see following errors:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in TestAppDomain.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AppDomainUnloadedException' in TestAppDomain.exe
```

I am not sure what is the issue here, how can I correctly unload such child AppDomain without killing Parent?

Comment: How does the code for *unloading* the `AppDomain` looks like? Do you get an exception? could you please share the error message?

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens', I just use "AppDomain.Unload(domain)" and then application quits with exitcode 0, but before than there is "AppDomainUnloadedException" and "Threading.ThreadAbortException". Added these in the question.

Comment: Do you actually have any code _after_ the `AppDomain.Unload` call that doesn't get called?

Comment: @Christian.K, yes, simple "Console.WriteLine("Unloaded");", but it does not get called.

Comment: @Puyebu as I wrote you need to see what kind of exception is raised. Add a `try/catch` around your unload code and examine the error.

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens', If I try to get "exception.message", I get "Thread has aborted." message in `try/catch` block.

Comment: as you are getting a `ThreadAbortException` I suggest you have a look at that error message, such as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22712991/3881834

Answer (score 0):

Main thread was not stopped completely before I tried to unload the AppDomain. 
Stopping it correctly fixed the error.